# ConstraintLayout set rounded corner by Shape Resource file doesn't work

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

I have met a strange problem, It didn't work when I set layout used for adapter item corners by `shape` resource file.

This is my `shape` resource file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="8dp" />
</shape>
```

This is my adapter item layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <import type="android.view.View.OnClickListener" />

        <import type="android.view.View" />

        <import type="com.zhixin.wedeep.homepage.data.model.BriefComposition" />

        <variable
            name="clickListener"
            type="OnClickListener" />

        <variable
            name="composition"
            type="BriefComposition" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="108dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="@drawable/homepage_shape_recommend_composition_background"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="@{clickListener}"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_label_is_new"
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="22dp"
            android:text="@string/homepage_new"
            android:textColor="@color/color_white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_10"
            android:visibility='@{composition.tag == "NEW" ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE}'
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="新上" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_view_cover"
            imageFromUrl="@{composition.cover}"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            tools:src="@drawable/gt3_new_bind_logo" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear_layout_text_area"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingStart="5dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_view_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="@{composition.title}"
                android:textColor="@color/color_white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_13"
                tools:text="助眠脑波" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_view_duration"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:text="@{composition.duration}"
                android:textColor="@color/color_white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_10"
                tools:text="5-30min" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

This is my `RecylerView` for display the above item layout

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view_recommendation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
    app:spanCount="3"
    tools:itemCount="6"
    tools:listitem="@layout/homepage_item_recommend_composition" />
```

This is my `RecylerView` Adapter

```
class RecommendCompositionsAdapter : ListAdapter<BriefComposition, RecommendCompositionsAdapter.ViewHolder>(BriefCompositionDiffCallback()) {


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(HomepageItemRecommendCompositionBinding.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        val briefComposition = getItem(position)
        briefComposition?.let {
            holder.apply {
                itemView.tag = it
                bind(createOnClickListener(it.id), it)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun createOnClickListener(id: String): View.OnClickListener {
        return View.OnClickListener {
            ARouter.getInstance().build(RouterConstant.PATH_AUDIO_PLAYER).withString(AudioPlayerActivity.KEY_ID, id).navigation()
        }
    }

    class ViewHolder(private val binding: HomepageItemRecommendCompositionBinding)
        : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        fun bind(listener: View.OnClickListener, item: BriefComposition
        ) {
            binding.apply {
                clickListener = listener
                composition = item
                // from View

                executePendingBindings()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas for this odd problem? Thank you in advance!

Comment: your shape xml name is homepage_shape_recommend_composition_background?

Comment: @ST yes, the ```shape``` xml name is that name.

Comment: can you make <corners android:radius="100dp"/>? or add color in shape? because I make xml following your code, it make radius.

Comment: @ST  I have tried your idea, But it seems doestn't work either. Additionally, I delete all ```databinding``` relative codes, What a pity that it still doesn't work. And i change ```ConstrainLayout``` to ```FrameLayout```, ```RelativeLayout```,```LinearLayout```. None of those ```layout``` works

Comment: I think your Layout xml file is fine. how about adapter class? is any set ui in class file?

Comment: @ST  I have changed my question and posted more details. Please take a look

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like even if you are setting the background of your `ConstraintLayout`, it is overlapped by the `ImageView` and hence you are not getting the shape that your `ConstraintLayout` has. I would recommend using a `CardView` instead of the `ConstraintLayout`. Set the drawable as the background of your `CardView` and put everything inside of your `CardView` as you have done it for the `ConstraintLayout`.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Yes, I just put my ConstraintLayout inside a CardViewLayout, The problem is solved.